# Create a paginate using KnpPaginator

Tags: php, symfony, pagination, symfony-2.1, knppaginator

I tried to create a pagination on my website using the bundle KnpPaginator.
In my repository I create a query :

```
public function getProductsOrderByDateDesc($id_category = null, $max = null){
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->orderBy('p.created_at', 'DESC');

    if($max) {
        $qb->setMaxResults($max);
    }
    if($id_category) {
        if(is_array($id_category)){
            $aIdCategory = implode("','",$id_category);
            $qb->andWhere('p.category IN (:ids)')
                ->setParameter('ids', $aIdCategory);
        }else{
            $qb->andWhere('p.category = :category_id')
                ->setParameter('category_id', $id_category);
        }
    }
    $query = $qb->getQuery();
    return $query->getArrayResult();
}
```

In my controller I do :

```
    $repositoryProduct = $em->getRepository('ShopDesktopBundle:Product');
    $aProducts          = array();
    $aProducts          = $repositoryProduct->getProductsOrderByDateDesc($id);
    $paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');
    $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
        $aProducts,
        $this->get('request')->query->get('page', 1),
        3
    );
    return $this->render('ShopDesktopBundle:Category:category.html.twig',array(
        'aProducts'         => $aProducts,
        'pagination'        => $pagination
    ));
```

In view I only show this pagination :

```
<div class="navigation">
     {{ knp_pagination_render(pagination) }}
</div>
```

The problem is that always displays all products not only the limit who for my example is 3.
For example : 
   I have 9 products, limit = 3, the pagination is correct "1 2 3" but for every page I see all 9 products
Help me please ! Thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Almost correct, however you have to use the pagination object instead of the 'aProducts'. In your view, use the following code:

```
{% for product in pagination %}
<tr {% if loop.index is odd %}class="color"{% endif %}>
    <td>{{ product.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ product.title }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

See more info in the documentation, under 'View': https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle

Comment: Now to pagination doen't work. Always stay on page = 1

Comment: Please read the documentation carefully, there is a complete example under 'Controller' which states you must use the Request object to actually get the pagination working: `$request->query->get('page', 1)`